# Better approach for implementing a function

Tags: c++

Let's assume Alice and Bob were assigned, for example, to implement a function, returning day of week for a given date of Gregorian calendar, assuming the specified date is valid and belongs to the Gregorian calendar.

Are there widely accepted guidelines (or best practices), allowing to tell whose code is better, and why?

Alice:

```
int getDayOfWeek(int day, int month, int year)
{
    int monthBias[] = { 0, 3, 3, 6, 1, 4, 6, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5 };
    int yearsBefore = year - 1;

    unsigned int result = yearsBefore + yearsBefore / 4 - yearsBefore / 100 + yearsBefore / 400 + monthBias[month - 1] + day;

    if (year % 4 == 0 && month > 2 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0))
        ++result;

    return result % 7;
}
```

Bob:

```
enum DayOfWeek
{
    Sunday,
    Monday,
    Tuesday,
    Wednesday,
    Thursday,
    Friday,
    Saturday,

    count
};

inline int getLeapYearsBefore(int year)
{
    int yearsBefore = year - 1;

    return yearsBefore / 4 - yearsBefore / 100 + yearsBefore / 400;
}

inline bool isLeapYear(int year)
{
    return year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0);
}

using namespace std;

template <typename T, size_t n>
constexpr size_t arraySize(T (&)[n]) { return n; }

DayOfWeek getDayOfWeek(int day, int month, int year)
{
    const int
        commonYear[] = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 },
        leapYear[] = { 31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 },

        daysInCommonYear = accumulate(commonYear, commonYear + arraySize(commonYear), 0),
        daysInLeapYear = accumulate(leapYear, leapYear + arraySize(leapYear), 0),

        yearsBefore = year - 1,
        leapYearsBefore = getLeapYearsBefore(year),
        commonYearsBefore = yearsBefore - leapYearsBefore;

    auto kindOfYear = isLeapYear(year) ? leapYear : commonYear;

    unsigned int result =
        (leapYearsBefore * daysInLeapYear
        + commonYearsBefore * daysInCommonYear
        + accumulate(kindOfYear, kindOfYear + month - 1, day)) % DayOfWeek::count;

    return static_cast<DayOfWeek>(result);
}
```

Performance comparison hasn't yield a detectable advantage for Alice's code, as I tried to measure the difference in performance of Alice's and Bob's implementations, but failed (using `high_resolution_clock::now()` and `duration_cast<nanoseconds>(end - start)`) - at least I can tell the difference is less than 0.5% (between average call durations across 5 million calls).

Comment: If I were asked to do this, I'd use the date libraries in Boost. (www.boost.org). But Alice's solution looks cleaner (and is the one I've studied in the past). Needs testing and some program comments though.

Comment: My vote goes to whoever ships their library with extensive test cases!

Comment: No, there is no general guideline. The reason is that in general requirements can be very different and different requirements (e.g. simplicity of code vs efficiency) can be conflicting. A good start to compare two functions would be to require both of them to have the same signature, so that they could be used interchangably.

Comment: PS: If one needs a function that returns an `int` Alices version is better, if you want a `enum` bobs is better.

Comment: OK, what if both implementations have the same return type? Does the flexibility of Bob's solution matter? He doesn't even require common and leap years to have the same number of months (and doesn't assume there are 7 days in a week). Next, what about maintainability?

Comment: Flexibility always comes at a cost and you have to make trade offs. If ever the number of days per week will change to 6, bob can handle this, but alice cant. Trade off: How likely is this to happen? How much effort had bob to spend (resulting in more verbose and more complicated code) to gain this flexibility? Btw, in case you mean "better" = more efficient, the best way to compare is to measure it.

Comment: Yes, I see your point, and it looks reasonable. As for performance, I couldn't detect that Alice's approach is faster. I tried to measure the difference in performance of Alice's and Bob's implementations, but failed (using `high_resolution_clock::now()` and `duration_cast<nanoseconds>(end - start)`) - at least the difference is less than 0.5% (between average call durations across 5 million calls).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always in life, there is no simple way of comparing the two approaches and different people may have different opinions about them. If those functions were to be incorporated into production code, two things would count:

1. How easy is it to understand, verify, and maintain the code. In that regard clearly Bob's approach wins. In Alice's code there two many "cryptic" numbers that are not obvious enough. At least some comments would help to understand how she arrived at that solution.
2. How fast does the code execute. That is what would count if this were a general library routine that is called millions of times. Just from looking at the code, I would guess that Alice's approach is slightly faster. But that is just an assumption, it would need to be measured on the desired platform.

So the "clear" answer is again: *It depends*.

Under the assumptions that Bob's code is only slightly slower and that the function is not all that performance critical I would vote for Bob's approach -- after doing some timings.

Comment: Concerning your first point, I would say that both versions fail to give a complete documentation and this could be fixed for both of them.  I do not agree that bob wins. Imho 3 functions and an enum are harder to understand/test/maintain than a single function

Comment: I agree some comments are needed, at least for Alice's code. As for performance, I couldn't detect that Alice's approach is slightly faster. I tried to measure the difference in performance of Alice's and Bob's implementations, but failed (using `high_resolution_clock::now()` and `duration_cast<nanoseconds>(end - start)`) - at least the difference is less than 0.5% (between average call durations across 5 million calls).

Comment: @tobi303: Yes, both version do need some more commenting. But Bob's code is more obvious as it parallels the rules of our calender system, while Alice's code is not obvious at all. And even Bob's code has three functions I would find it easier to review and maintain than Alice's code. But that is certainly personal opinion.

Comment: @user3900460: If both solutions turn out about to be the same performance wise that's interesting. And it would let me even more tend towards Bob's code.

Answer (score 2):

if you're looking for guidelines I suggest you to read the C++ Programming Language Book of Stroustrup .

But briefly those are are two different approach :

Alice method (why it should be used):
Simple approach used for program requiring high performance
- one function (one call) 
- Declaring variable only when it is needed
- using statically allocated vector with a known size
- no exhaustive use of object copies.

Bob method (why it should be used):

It is based on the divide and conquer strategy .
-every function is responsible of a single task (useful if you want to maintain code in the future)
-a highly reusable code for other purposes.

Comment: You mentioned "high performance" regarding Alice's approach. I tried to measure the difference in performance of Alice's and Bob's implementations, but failed (using `high_resolution_clock::now()` and `duration_cast<nanoseconds>(end - start)`) - at least the difference is less than 0.5% (between average call durations across 5 million calls).

Comment: I was talking in a generic way , you will not get a big difference for this example but with a millions of code lines Alice code style will surely have better bench marking results.

Answer (score -1):

They are different as @tobi303 said, but I see first implementation has less computation, and the second is more understandable.

if they where similar, you can compare by test cases it pass as mentioned, and performance measurements (i.e, execution time).

**Edit**: "I see" the second is understandable, because of meaningful identifiers.

```
year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0)
```

I would not know what does it mean to have true result, if I do not read the function name.

Comment: "more understandable" is purely subjective and actually if this is the measure, i would go for the first one

Comment: @tobi303: how can you say that ? The first version has obscure magical numbers like 3, 3, 6, or 497 that require serious reflection, while the second is quite narrative and only uses well-known facts.

Comment: I can say that, because imho without further documentation 3,3,6,497 is  just as magical as 1,4,100,400,31... On the other hand, with proper documentation both versions can be "de-mystified".

Comment: Absolutely, but we are comparing them without documentation, and saying  that code is easier to understand does not mean it is perfect.

Comment: PS: which one is better is not really the point, but my point is: it is mainly subjective to decide which on is more understandable. I can say, that I better understand the first one because it is a fact (a subjective one)

Comment: @tobi303 It is common knowledge that years are leap every other 4 but not every other 100 but every other 400, and you recognize at a glance the lengths of the months. The choice of identifiers leaves no ambiguity.

Comment: I tried to measure the difference in performance of Alice's and Bob's implementations, but failed (using `high_resolution_clock::now()` and `duration_cast<nanoseconds>(end - start)`) - at least the difference is less than 0.5% (between average call durations across 5 million calls).